# How to prove Codim $V(I + J) \leq$ Codim $V(I) + $ Codim $V(J)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I_1, I_2, I_3$ be three ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, .., x_n]$.
Let $V(J) = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n : f(\mathbf{x}) = 0  \ for \ all \ f \in J \}$.

How can I prove that  Codim $V(I_1 + I_2 + I_3) \leq$ Codim $V(I_1) + $ Codim $V(I_2)$ + Codim $V(I_3)$ ?

Here, Codim $V(I_j) = n - \dim V(I_j)$ and by dimension I mean as an algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Any comments are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The title has two ideals, the body has three. Anyway, the statement for two ideals extends easily to any finite sum.

Comment: @egreg Right, and how does one prove this for two ideals?

Answer (score 1):

Let us fix once for all times in the sequel the polynomial ring $A=\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$, which is noetherian, in it two ideals $$I,\ J$$ generated by
$$f_1,\dots, f_i\in A\ ,$$
and respectively
$$g_1,\dots, g_j\in A\ .$$
We can and do assume that $i, j$ are minimal with these properties.

Let $K$ be the ideal generated by $I$ and $J$,
$$ K = I+J\ ,$$
it has the generators
$$f_1,\dots, f_i\ ;\ g_1,\dots, g_j\in A\ ,$$
but this list may not be minimal. (E.g. for $I=J$ non-trivial ideal.)

The question is now related and follows from "dimension theory". The dimension can be defined in various ways:[Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_variety)

From the list, there are at least three "worlds", categories, mathematical domains, where the notion can be defined, and which are relevant for the question. These are:

- For an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ we can define its **height**. A notion of "dimension" is not used commonly for ideals, but it is used for commutative rings. In our case, this notion applies for $R$ and the quotient ring $R/I$, and it is called **Krull dimension**. Reference: [Krull_dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension). This is a purely algebraic object.

  In both cases, the definitions deal with the length of chains of *prime* ideals, ordered by strict inclusions. (The number of the strict inclusions in the chain is the length.)

  (In order to relate $\dim A$ with $\dim (A/I)$ and the height of $I$, one has to find a natural way to "combine" and/or reduce chains. In the p.o.-set of ideals, one can consider the ideals that can be compared with $I$, and only chains going through this "strangulated" po-set. Then one needs a way to ensure same lenght of maximal chains - under favorable circumstances, we have such a situation.)
- For an (affine) algebraic variety $X$ we have a dimension. This is defined in the algebraic geometry by passing to affine coverings, writing each affine piece as a Spec(trum) of a ring, then using the Krull dimension for rings.
- For a differential manifold $M$ over $\mathbb C$ we also have a notion of dimension, this is defined by using charts (near regular points) to open domains in the one or other standard affine space $\mathbb C^k$ for some fixed $k$. (This is the dimension of $M$.) To an (affine) algebraic variety $X$ as in the posted question, 
  $$ X = \text{Spec}(A/I)\ ,$$
  we can associate the corresponding manifold 
  $$M=X(\mathbb C)\ ,$$
  which is as a set $V(I)$. Moreover, the projection 
  $$ A\to A/I$$
  induces the map (of ringed topological spaces)
  $$ \text{Spec} A \leftarrow \text{Spec} (A/I)\ ,$$
  which is
  $$ \mathbb C^n\leftarrow V(I)\ .$$
  The left arrows are inclusions. The codimension in the question is taken with respect to these canonical inclusions for $I,J;K$.

The inequality $\text{codim} V(I+J)\le \text{codim} V(I) +\text{codim} V(J)$ follows now as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{codim} V(I) &= \dim \mathbb C^n -\dim V(I) = \dim A -\dim(A/I) = \text{height}(I) 
\\
&= i\ ,
\\\\
\text{codim} V(J) &= \dim \mathbb C^n -\dim V(J) = \dim A -\dim(A/J) = \text{height}(J) 
\\
&= j\ ,
\\\\
\text{codim} V(I+J) &= \dim \mathbb C^n -\dim V(I+J) = \dim A -\dim(A/(I+J)) = \text{height}(I+J) 
\\
&\le i+j\ .
\end{align}

Here, we have tacitly used the passage

- from chains of systems of generators like $()\subset (f_1)\subset\dots\subset (f_1,\dots,f_i)$
- to chains of prime ideals included in $I$.

which is Krull's principal ideal theorem as stated here:
[Consequences...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theory_(algebra)#Consequences_of_the_fundamental_theorem)

In most proofs, one needs [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).

Comment: Thank you very much for this!!! :)

Comment: You say codim $V(I) = i$, but this means $V(I)$ is a complete intersection... but I thought not all ideals were complete intersections?